# Shared model between parent and children controllers in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewController, the parent (or container) which as properties has two more viewControllers, one that is `listViewController` and the other that is `elementViewController`.

The "model", in this case an array of objects `[Element]`, and is passed to the children controllers upon instantiation with `listViewController.model = model` and `elementViewController.model = model`.

In the listViewController I have a button that performs an action to add a new element to the array, so it does something like: `model.append(Element())` and then collapses the current view and executes on it's delegate, which is the `containerViewController` the `showElement(forIndex:)` with as index `model.count-1` to get the index of the last element added.

This method calls on the child `elementViewController` the `showElement(forIndex:)` method, which is supposed to show details for the `model[index]` element passing through the index, but when the latter function is performed it appears that the index is out of range, the reason being that the model on the parent controller is not updated, since Array is passed by value (the debugger confirms this, showing one element less in the `containerviewController`).

The temporary solution for this to pass to the `showElement` method the updated array, and replace the parent model, but I don't like it.

The option I would rather use is to have the array passed as reference instead of value to the models, so that when one element is added the models on the `containerViewController` and the `elementViewController` are in sync automatically.

Is there any drawbacks in my theoretical implementation? And if not, how would I achieve this?

Is wrapping the array in an elementsCollection class so that it's passed as reference to the children model a clean way to go or should I try to find a completely different solution?

TL;DR Is wrapping an array in a class reasonable to pass the model as reference to children viewControllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of a `struct` are kept separate. Instances of a `class` are shared. `Array` is a `struct`.

I think the simplest way to get what you want is to wrap your array in a class.

```
class MyModel {
    var elements: [Element] = []
}
```

Have all of your view controllers can share an instance of `MyModel`. They can modify `elements` all they want and it will be shared with the other view controllers.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I was held back by the thought it might be a bad decision architecturally speaking.

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni I've had to do this a few times. I always seem to create something that looks like a view model which wraps any data needed by a set of view controllers.